# I cant install flask in my project i write pip install flask and when i write flask --version it doesn't recognize it?

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install flask
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from flask) (8.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from flask) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from flask) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from flask) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from click>=7.1.2->flask) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\muden\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask) (2.0.1)
```

What is the problem Pleaz?

Comment: the problem is "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"

Comment: @Anentropic thanks bro but how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: @Anentropic check my answer below

Comment: try following some beginner tutorials and resources like https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score -1):

can u try that after creating a virtual environment inside your folder,

steps to create virtual env and using it are here:

step 1:

```
    python -m venv venv
```

step 2 for linux :

```
    source venv/bin/activate
```

step 2 for windows :

```
     source venv\Scripts\activate
```

step 3 : now install your projects requirement here and try running using flask it will work.

```
    pip install flask

    flask --version
```

Comment: thanks man I'm sorry but the script in step 3 in which folder i should run it Sorry I'm just getting started ?

Comment: run all these commands in your project root directory....so that the virtual env will be created in your root dir, the commands are to be executed in terminal

Comment: it doesn't recognize source ?

Comment: source is command too, try googling

Comment: @ Surya R I just wrote venv\Scripts\activate and it worked for me you are a legend man thank you so much for the help

Comment: yeah, welcome..an upvote and making this answer as correct or accpetable answer will appreciate me

Comment: So basically whenever i want to enter my project i have to write venv\Scripts\activate In order to read flask ?